# how to get tuple with average(xxx) by spring data jpa specification?

Tags: spring, repository, spring-data-jpa, criteria, specifications

I want to get the `List<Map<String,Object>>`returned by query like this:

```
[{production:{the object}, avgscore:123}, {production:{other object},avgscore:456}, ...]
```

I can get it by this :

```
public interface ProductionRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Production, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT p as productions,avg(c.score) as avgscore FROM ......")
    List<Map<String,Object>> findSorted(......);
}
```

but now I try to use Specification, and I done the specification:

```
Specification specification = new Specification() {
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root root1, CriteriaQuery query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
            .......
            .......
            if (date2 != null) {
                Predicate endTimeP = cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get(Production_.productDate), date2);
                predicates.add(endTimeP);
            }
            query.groupBy(root.get(Production_.id)).orderBy(cb.desc(cb.avg(commentJoin.get(Comment_.score))));
            Predicate[] predicates1 = new Predicate[predicates.size()];
            predicates.toArray(predicates1);
            query.multiselect(root.alias("production"),
                    cb.avg(commentJoin.get(Comment_.score)).as(Double.class).alias("avgscore"));
            return cb.and(predicates1);
}
```

and then I use this to findAll:

```
return specificationRepo.findAll(specification);
```

the repository is:

```
@Repository
public interface SpecificationRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Production, Long>,
        JpaSpecificationExecutor {
    List<Map<String,Object>> findAll(Specification specification);
}
```

BUT, the findAll() only return `List<Production>` , no matter how I change the return type, it always return `List<production>` , not `List<Map<String,Object>>` I wanted.

it it bind to the Production in `PagingAndSortingRepository<Production, Long>`. If I delete this and only have JpaSpecificationExecutor, spring will not seem it as a @Repository; The Production position must be a @Entity, I can not change it to a custom java thing having Production and avgscore.

I have searched long time, but still didn't find how to solve.

Comment: do you find a solution?

Comment: use native sql...